# Cannot select json array from rest api using Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am new to swift and I am trying to get a link from a json file using  Alamofire. I have been searching google for days now and have not found any useful solutions. I am not that good with json arrays. 
I need the link from (_links.https://api.w.org/featuredmedia.href) this is my code:

```
guard let ide = self.json[0]["_links"]["https:\/\/api.w.org\/featuredmedia"]["href"].string else{
        print("Request failed with error")
        return
}
    print(ide)


    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://tricitychurchofchrist.com/wp-json/wp/v2/ctc_sermon/5640").responseJSON { response in
            guard let _ = response.result.value else{
                print("Request failed with error")
                return
            }
    }
```

And here is the json:

```
{
"id": 5854,
"date": "2016-01-17T20:22:28",
"date_gmt": "2016-01-17T20:22:28",
"guid": {
    "rendered": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/?post_type=ctc_sermon&#038;p=5854"
},
"modified": "2016-01-18T19:16:10",
"modified_gmt": "2016-01-18T19:16:10",
"slug": "inviting-the-lightaudio-upload",
"type": "ctc_sermon",
"link": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/sermons\/inviting-the-lightaudio-upload\/",
"title": {
    "rendered": "Inviting The Light"
},
"content": {
    "rendered": ""
},
"excerpt": {
    "rendered": ""
},
"author": 1,
"featured_image": 2007,
"comment_status": "closed",
"ping_status": "closed",
"_links": {
    "self": [{
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/ctc_sermon\/5854"
    }],
    "collection": [{
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/ctc_sermon"
    }],
    "about": [{
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/ctc_sermon"
    }],
    "author": [{
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/1"
    }],
    "replies": [{
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/comments?post=5854"
    }],
    "version-history": [{
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/ctc_sermon\/5854\/revisions"
    }],
    "https:\/\/api.w.org\/featuredmedia": [{
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media\/2007"
    }],
    "https:\/\/api.w.org\/attachment": [{
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media?parent=5854"
    }],
    "https:\/\/api.w.org\/term": [{
        "taxonomy": "ctc_sermon_topic",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/ctc_sermon\/5854\/ctc_sermon_topic"
    }, {
        "taxonomy": "ctc_sermon_book",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/ctc_sermon\/5854\/ctc_sermon_book"
    }, {
        "taxonomy": "ctc_sermon_series",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/ctc_sermon\/5854\/ctc_sermon_series"
    }, {
        "taxonomy": "ctc_sermon_speaker",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/ctc_sermon\/5854\/ctc_sermon_speaker"
    }, {
        "taxonomy": "ctc_sermon_tag",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/ctc_sermon\/5854\/ctc_sermon_tag"
    }]
}}
```

I am using WP REST API fro the json from the wordpress site.

Comment: This JSON is not an array, but an object. You shouldn't  access it by index (json[0]["_links"]), try json["_links"]...

Comment: But there is an array in my json correct **"self": [{
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/ctc_sermon\/5854"
    }]** and how do I access this **"_links": {
    "self": [{
        "href": "http:\/\/tricitychurchofchrist.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/ctc_sermon\/5854"
    }]**

Answer (score 0):

the data type you returnd is object type,you should change it to JSON object,you can use [SwiftJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git) open source on github,and code like this:

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
        .response { request, response, data, error in
            let jsonval = JSON(data:data!)
            let jsonDic:NSDictionary = jsonval.object as! NSDictionary

    }
```

jsonDic is now a NSDictionary type,change NSDictionary to NSArray, and you can use it directly,hope help